# How to bind dynamic column names as Field?

Tags: jooq

Using jOOQ 3.16 and SQLDialect.MYSQL, I would like to set up parameter binding for a list of dynamic column names. I am using jOOQ as a query builder only.

So far the closest I got is `select(field(name(column_name)))` which would escape the column name with back-ticks (because I am using MySQL). This would work for me but it is not actually binding the column names as parameters:

```
select `column_name` from ...
```

If I try to use either `select(field(val(column_name)))` or `select(field(inline(column_name)))`, then after binding the dynamic column name would be automatically escaped using single-quotes, which would make them string literals and make the query return string literals as well:

```
select 'column_name' from ...
```

Is there a better way to bind dynamic column names? The same issue exists for binding dynamic table names as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot "bind column names" in SQL. SQL isn't such a dynamic language, the column names, table names, and other identifiers have to be provided statically in a query. So, it doesn't make sense to attempt to "bind" identifiers using `val()`

But with jOOQ, obviously, you can create dynamic SQL. [Every jOOQ query is a dynamic SQL query, see also the manual](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dynamic-sql/).

You don't *have to* embed your fields in the query. It's just Java code, like any other. You can assign things to local variables, e.g.:

```java
Field<?> field = field(name(columnName));
Query q = select(field);
```

Or

```java
List<Field<?>> fields = List.of(field(name(columnName)));
Query q = select(fields);
```

Or

```java
List<Field<?>> fields = new ArrayList<>();
fields.add(field(name(columnName)));
Query q = select(fields);
```

I mean, there is really no limitation to what you dynamically with jOOQ. But once you generate the SQL string, the query becomes static for the database.

Comment: Thanks! What I meant by "bind column names" is to separate the SQL string itself and the select column names as bind parameters, similar to what I can do with the where clauses described here https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/bind-values/named-parameters/. So that I can get `select ?, ? from ...` as the SQL string and call `bind(0, "column_name")` on frameworks like JDBC. Looks like this won't be possible with jOOQ and `field(name(column_name))` would be the closest thing?

Comment: @qwertghjkl: There's no JDBC driver nor RDBMS I'm aware of that lets you bind an identifier to a bind parameter marker `?`. This isn't specific to jOOQ. You cannot do that with vanilla JDBC either.